# Java Abstract Class (this keyword)

Tags: java, android

I think I'm misunderstanding something, and if so, I need help..

Let's say I have the following two classes:

```
public abstract class Abstraction() {
   protected int number = 0;
   public void printNumber() {
       System.out.println(this.number);
       System.out.println(getNumber());
   }
   public int getNumber() {
       return this.number();
   }
}

public class Reality extends Abstraction {
   int number = 1;
   public Reality() {
       this.printNumber();
   }
}

// some other class
new Reality();
```

What should the output be? I'm getting 0, 0 (the code here is a bit more complicated but still the same issue).
How can I get the output to be 1,1?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `number` in the `Reality` class ***doesn't*** overwrite the `number` in the `Abstraction` class. Therefore, the `Abstraction` class still sees his own `number` value as `0`.

A solution would be:

```
public class Reality extends Abstraction {
   public Reality() {
       number = 1;
       this.printNumber();
   }
}
```

Because your `number` in `Abstraction` is protected, you can access it in your `Reality` class.

---

Another example is a parameter in a method:

```
private int number;

public void myMethod(int number){
    number = 2;
}
```

Your `private int number` *field* won't be set, instead, the *parameter* `number` will be set as `2`.

---

Finally, a word on the `this` and `super` keywords, see an edit of your classes:

```
public abstract class Abstraction() {
   protected int number = 0;
   public void printNumber() {
       System.out.println(this.number);
       System.out.println(getNumber());
   }
   public int getNumber() {
       return this.number();
   }
}

public class Reality extends Abstraction {
   int number = 1;
   public Reality() {
       System.out.println(number); //Will print 1
       System.out.println(this.number); //Will print 1
       System.out.println(super.number); //Will print 0
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a *local* variable in `Reality` but the `printNumber()` method refers to the the member variable which is still 0.

If you don't create a local varible but you use the field instead like this:

```
number = 1;
```

it will be OK.

If you have problems understanding fields you can always refer to the *official* documentation which can be found here: [Oracle java docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html)

Answer (score 1):

You could create setter methods in the abstract class:

```
public void setNumber(int value) {
this.number = value;
}
```

They way you are trying to achieve this won't work, since the variable doesn't overrite that of the super class.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

```
public class Reality extends Abstraction {
    int number = 1;
    public Reality() {
        this.printNumber();
    }
}
```

Above the code `number` is an instance variable Of class `Reality` and calling method of super class. In super class `printNumber()` method will print value of `number` 0 because it is initialized with 0.

If you want to get subclass variable value of `number`, you have to pass value as method argument as follows:

```
public Reality(int num) {
    this.printNumber();
}
```